# Owl carousel in Angular 7

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

I use the Owl carousel in Angular 7.
In First I install With

```
 npm install ngx-owl-carousel owl.carousel jquery --save
```

Then add

```
 "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
 "./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"]
```

In angular.json file
and add

```
import { OwlModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel';
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 OwlModule
]
```

in app.module.ts file
Then I Used

```
public ngOnInit()
{
 /*----------------------------
        Slideshow
    ------------------------------ */
    $('.slideshow').owlCarousel({
      items: 6,
      autoPlay: 3000,
      singleItem: true,
      navigation: true,
      navigationText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'],
      pagination: true
  });
}
```

In app.component.ts file, But I have error

> core.js:14576 ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).owlCarousel is not a function

where am I mistake ? Please  help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use this version for Angular 7: [ngx-owl-carousel-o](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After importing OwlModule you are able to use its exported components inside your Angular templates like below (example taken from [github repo](https://github.com/mujtaba01/ngx-owl-carousel)):

```
   <owl-carousel
     [options]="{items: 3, dots: false, navigation: false}"
     <!-- If images array is dynamically changing pass this array to [items] 
     input -->
    [items]="images"
    <!-- classes to be attached along with owl-carousel class -->
      [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let image of images;let i = index">
       <div class="thumbnail-image" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(abc.jpg) 
       no-repeat scroll center center / 80px 80px'}"></div>
    </div>
   </owl-carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

install jquery and owl carousel

```
npm install --save jquery

npm install --save owl.carousel
```

Import the library in the component ts file where you need to work with owl carousel

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import "owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min"
declare var $:any;
```

Import the owl carousel stylesheet in global stylesheet - styles.css

```
@import "~owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min";
```

Comment: How did you initialise owlCarousel afterwards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485022/declare-let-any-flagged-by-typescript-eslint-no-explicit-any-rule